# How do I insert a date into mysql table using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datetime

I am using a datetimepicker from jQuery, and when I select a date from the datetimepicker it puts it in this format:

```
  11/10/2011 14:02
```

Now when I try to insert it into my sql table like this

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (date, name) values ('$_POST[datepicker]','$_POST[name]')
```

it says the date is not in the correct format.

Can someone please help me determine how to format such date so that it is accepted by the datetime() field ?

Thank you

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '14:33:00,1,2,'Y')' at line 2

        $datetosave = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST[date]));

$insert_q = "INSERT INTO reservations (res_date, res_numofseats, user_id, rsvp)
                     VALUES ($datetosave,$_POST[cars],2,'Y')";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format, eg: `2011-11-10 14:02`.

Ideally, you'd want to set up your jQuery plugin to output in the correct format. If that's not possible, you can convert it to the correct format by parsing the date using PHP's [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) functions:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('11/10/2011 14:02')); 
// prints 2011-11-10 14:02:00
```

**Reference:** [MySQL Manual on `DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: would be too much to ask for a quick example on how to modify the jquery to put the right format? or to how to use the strtotime().

Comment: @user975582 Do you have  a link to the plugin in question?

Comment: To expand on that thought, the correct format for mysql column is `date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", $unixtime);`

Comment: [Panos's answer to this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date) shows how to do it in jQuery

Comment: i still cant get it please see above for my code. if i remove the 14:00 thing.. it saves all zeros

Comment: You are missing the quotes around the `$datetosave` in your Query.

Comment: @user975582 That should be `VALUES ('$datetosave', $_POST[cars], -- etc ...`

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's date function to convert it to MySQL's datetime format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:I:S)

`$mytime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('11/10/2011 14:02'));`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is lack of quotes around the inserted date:

```
$insert_q = "INSERT INTO reservations (res_date, res_numofseats, user_id, rsvp)
VALUES ($datetosave,$_POST[cars],2,'Y')";
```

gives you VALUES 2011-11-10 14:33:00,1,2,'Y'

Add ticks around $datetosave

```
$insert_q = "INSERT INTO reservations (res_date, res_numofseats, user_id, rsvp)
VALUES ('".$datetosave."',$_POST[cars],2,'Y')";
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be out of the scope of your question, but your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. Try to always use inbuilt escaping/quoting methods of your database library or use the prepared statements. Not sure what library are you using, so few links here (I would paste more but SE does not allow me to do so :) ):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php